# onConfigurationChanged-it's still showing the first layout

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an activity which handles configuration changes. But now i have to change 
layout.I tried in onConfigurationChanged callback just to set again the layout and hoping will get the correct layout(land) but it's still showing 
the first layout for portrait view ( there two layout(same name) are placed in res/ 
layout and res/layout-land :)

if I delete android:configChanges="orientation", it works should be, but ı need to handle onConfigurationChanged. What should I do??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have your portrait layout `main.xml` in `/res/layout` and your landscape layout `main.xml` in `/res/layout-land`, and your `onConfigurationChanged()` looks like this:

```
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);                
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ...
    ...
    ...

    }
```

And in your Manifest you should have `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`

Then it should work fine, as this does in my app. Is this what you are doing?

Comment: yes it works fine:)) thank you... I want to ask, why we should write keyboardHidden??

Comment: I think because on some devices when someone slides open the keyboard that also changes the orientation automatically.

Comment: can you help me ? its not working for me. i have two different xml file in different folder. i have add android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" and also your code format but its not working,

Comment: I was inflating layout and it kept on giving me crashes. I didn't even realise that the solution to all my problems would be in a single line.

Answer (score 4):

```
// In your activity code.
int mCurrentOrientation;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mfo_offers);
    ........
    mCurrentOrientation = getCurrentOrientation();
}
@Override    
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // You may handle different configuration changes in your activity which configured in your mainfest.xml, you only need to recreate layout when orientation changes.
        if(mCurrentOrientation != newConfig.orientation) {          
            recreate(); // This recreate the activity if you can properly restore your activity state.  
        }
        ......
}
```

See Activity.recreate() here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()

Comment: public void recreate () (Added in API level 11)

Cause this Activity to be recreated with a new instance. This results in essentially the same flow as when the Activity is created due to a configuration change -- the current instance will go through its lifecycle to onDestroy() and a new instance then created after it.