# changing orientation through onConfigurationChanged()?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

Guys sorry if sounds a little bit naive...
In an activity I have one button and 4 textViews.

According to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003225/onconfigurationchanged-its-still-showing-the-first-layout) , I've changed the manifest file and overridden onConfigurationChanged(). I get the desired layout. BUT
 the button looses its onClickListener and also textViews change their text to what I set in xml initially.

How can I assign onClickListener to the button as it is set to the button in onCreate().
Also setText("anything") is called inside onCreate() for each textView.
What is the correct way of using onConfigurationChanged()? because it seems that I have to initiate everything again?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do again what you did in onCreate, because layout objects are recreated. I usually write a method that does all the view init work and call it both in onCreate and onConfigurationChanged.