# How to switch between portrait and landscape layout without activity restart?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I would like to switch between the portrait and landscape layout of an Activity without restarting it. To **avoid the activity restart** I have added this line to the activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

In my Activity i am overriding the Method

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
    ...
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
}
```

I have generated two files for the different layouts:

- res/layout/my_layout.xml
- res/layout-land/my_layout.xml

All elements in these layouts are using the same `id`s, in order to keep the behavior of the rest of the app consistent.

How do I programmatically switch between the two layouts in `onConfigurationChanged`?

`setContentView` is causing a `InflateException`, because the layout elements are already instantiated. Updating the resource configuration does nothing at all (most probably because doing this in `onConfigurationChanged` would be recursive).

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003225/onconfigurationchanged-its-still-showing-the-first-layout, you need to call `setContentView (R.layout.my_layout)` in `onConfigurationChanged()`

Comment: I think the best way is to save the instance bundle, so when orientation changes triggers `cnCreate()`c you can check if the bundle has something; just get the saved data. If it's empty it's because is the first time launching the activity.

Comment: Also the layouts should switch by themselves if the are created correctly, chek [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor#create-variant)

Comment: @CSmith: as I wrote above, `setContentView` would try recreate the fragments instead of reusing them. This does not work.

Comment: @javdromero: the layouts cannot switch by themselves, because I am overriding `onConfigurationChanged`. Otherwise the whole Activity would be restarted.

Comment: Please show your layouts, sounds like you just need a placeholder (i.e. `FragmentContainerView`) in your layouts and to instantiate your fragments programmatically so you have more control over their lifecycle.